# Calling a Function stored in Variable from jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I am trying to call a function typed variable from jQuery code. But don't know how to do that. **eval()** takes **string** input but I have function typed variable. I have tried the following code

```
if($.isFunction(successCallback)){
    window[successCallback]();
}
```

Comment: `$.isFunction(errorCallBack)` is working perfectly. It gives me **true** but I am not able the call that function @Satpal

Comment: What is this: `window[errorCallBack]();`?

Comment: @mmgross I was trying call the `errorCallBack` as this is function typed variable. I am able to do that using `errorCallBack.call()`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question has been updated to the point that there isnt a problem to fix anymore

Answer (score 1):

Calling like a normal function worked.

`successCallback()`

Comment: @atmd Looks like I was doing silly mistakes. Thanks man. It worked. Updated answer